# Xamarin - How to know which file was chosen by user

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want the user to select a file (only of the types .jpeg, .pdf and .png). When the user selects a file, I want to get the base64 string of the chosen file. How can I get the file chosen by user?

**Update:**
My code looks like this:
`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetType("image/*");
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Open images"), 1000);`

Comment: Selection of a file can be done on multiple ways. So the question is: What have you done so far?

Comment: @tequilaslammer I'm just opening an intent to open gallery, or Files folder using the code (i updated my question). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity/Fragment, whenever you a start an intent/activity with StartActivityforResult, the result will be returned to you on

> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
>   Intent data)

method, request code would be 1000 in your code and resultcode can be "RESULT_OK" OR "RESULT_CANCELLED" and data represents the result data. And you can access the picked image from data.

For reference : http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/